# Loop proceeding each row in query

Tags: mysql, sql, loops

There are two tables:

TABLE 1: My books

```
BOOK     PRICE
book1    45
book2    21
book3    7
book4    95
book5    32
etc
```

TABLE 2: Not my books

```
OWNER     BOOK     PRICE
owner1    book1    32
owner2    book1    14
owner2    book2    3
owner3    book3    7
owner4    book4    3
etc
```

**So, in table 1 we have only one book1, only one book2, etc. In the table2 we can have one or many books1, or books2, etc.**

**I want to know lowest difference in price between my books (table1) and not my books (table2). (This order is important, doesn’t matter if I obtain a negative value in price).**

In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
price (of books1 from table1) - price (of books1 from table2)
```

Given that we can have many prices for books1 in the table2, I have to do something like this

```
price (of book1 from table1) - price1 (of book1 from table2)
price (of book1 from table1) - price2 (of book1 from table2)
….
```

And after, select the minimum value between obtained results.

The logic of my current query is:

```
SELECT
table1.price - table2.price
FROM
table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.book = table2.book
```

But it doesn’t work because it returns more than 1 row (for table2).

**So my question is: Do I have to use a loop (cursor??? can I use it here?) or there is any other way to do this?**

Many thanks for any advice!

**EDIT**

I tried

```
SELECT
min(table1.price - table2.price) AS ‘price difference’
FROM
table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.book = table2.book
```

It doesn’t work.

Expected result:

```
BOOK    PRICE DIFFERENCE
book1    13
book2    18
book3    0
    etc
```

Comment: You should provide expected results also.. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Seams mine answer which i posted for your edit will give you those expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this query, but hard to say for sure without expected results. 
The `CASE END` is there to make the result always positive with `(my_books.PRICE - not_my_books.PRICE) * -1` if `books.PRICE - not_my_books.PRICE` is a negative number. 
I know MySQL supports `ABS()` to do the  same, but this query is ANSI SQL so it will work in most database systems.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   my_books.BOOK
 , MIN(
     CASE 
       WHEN my_books.PRICE - not_my_books.PRICE < 0
       THEN (my_books.PRICE - not_my_books.PRICE) * -1 
       ELSE my_books.PRICE - not_my_books.PRICE 
     END
   ) AS price_difference
FROM 
 my_books
INNER JOIN
 not_my_books
ON
 my_books.BOOK = not_my_books.BOOK
GROUP BY 
  my_books.BOOK
```

**Result**

```
| BOOK  | price_difference |
| ----- | ---------------- |
| book1 | 13               |
| book2 | 18               |
| book3 | 0                |
| book4 | 29               |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dWifZ1ztZTK4r84URFkHnY/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `min` grouping operator

```
SELECT my_books.BOOK,
min(abs(table1.price - table2.price))
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.book = table2.book
group by my_books.BOOK
```

Comment: what is the problem? can you elaborate it?

Comment: The problem? This will only give one record without `GROUP BY table1.BOOK` clause which is most likely the problem..

Comment: Yes my bad :) @user198493 can you please check my solution again?